# Log4j2 Asynclogger not logging full data

Tags: log4j2

Below is my configuration. Whenever I run the code, many error logs are missing at the end.
Is this a problem with the Asynclogger? I am using 2.0-rc1.

```xml
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
<RollingFile name="APP.ALERT" 
  fileName="C:\Users\sbasheer\Downloads\splunklogs\Alert.log" 
  filePattern="C:\Users\abc\Downloads\abclogs\Alert%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d | %5p %t %n %X{eventUUID} %c:%M(%L) : %m %n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50"/>
</RollingFile>
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n" />
</Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<AsyncLogger name="com.abc.asyncsample"  level="trace" includeLocation="true"> 
  <AppenderRef ref="APP.ALERT" level="error"/>
</AsyncLogger>
<Root level="info" includeLocation="true">
  <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Code:

```java
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
    logger.error("Error::" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue with the (patched) configuration above, but it works fine. I see the logs in both the console and the file, and the final log entry in both destinations reads "Error::99999" as expected.

When you say "many error logs are missing at the end", what is the last entry you are seeing? Also, the sample code does not show, is the logger created with LogManager.getLogger("com.abc.asyncsample")? (or with a class in the "com.abc.asyncsample" package, that would be fine too)?

I noticed that you have a size-based rollover policy configured for 25MB. If you run the above sample code three times, the file size will exceed 25MB and a rollover is triggered around "Error::94918" (on a Windows PC). After the rollover, the Alert.log file will contain the remaining entries "Error::94919" to "Error::99999", as expected.

Could it be that you were seeing the rollover results and concluded by mistake that events were dropped?

---

UPDATE:

I was testing with trunk which is why I could not reproduce the issue. This is a known issue of rc1 (LOG4J2-392/LOG4J2-520) and has been fixed in trunk. The fix will be in the next release (rc2).

Essentially this is a problem in the shutdown sequence for log4j2-rc1, where Appenders get disconnected from their Loggers before the Logger queue is fully drained. As a workaround, you could make your application sleep for some time before exiting.

Comment: static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppAsyncMain.class);

Comment: when i run for 100,000, last event is see is : 2014-06-16 14:49:57,938 | ERROR main 
  com.abc.abc.asyncsample.AppAsyncMain:main(21) : Error::98949

Comment: No, the file is just 11 MB. it didnt roll over.

Comment: Clearly, some logs are missing. Some runs, it gives all data. So the issue is intermittent.

Comment: private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("com.americanexpress.splunk.asyncsample"); Still logs are missing

Comment: Please raise a Jira ticket in the log4j2 issue tracker. Ideally attach a small program & config that can reproduce the issue. EDIT: I see you raised LOG4J2-672. Thanks, I'll take another look.

Comment: Does the above answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. The workaround worked, will use the code from Trunk to test the fix.